# Deriving the Bayes Optimal Classifier (Mitchell, Machine Learning)

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, bayes-theorem

I am trying to recreate the Bayes Optimal Classifier result given in Machine Learning textbook by Mitchell. Below, I've added the desired result from the text and my work.

I think I've taken the right approach but the final equality has a difference in the conditional. Is my approach incorrect or is there an intuitive  rationalization for why the conditionals are really the same?

**DESIRED RESULT**

[image: Formula]

**MY DERIVATION**

[image: Derivation]

Comment: When you search "derivation of Bayes formula," which of the 13,500,000 hits did you find was unclear?

Comment: My question wasn't about deriving the "Bayes formula" or the Naive Bayes classifier. If you had reviewed my image, you would've seen the result I was trying to recreate. Regardless, I should've been more specific in my question. It's updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$P(v_j|D) = \sum_{h_i}P(v_j|h_i,D)P(h_i|D)$$ by the law of total probability.

I think the key to understand the equality iswe have $P(v_j|h_i, D)=P(v_j|h_i)$, that is given the hypothesis, that is the hypothesis determines the probability of $v$ taking the values of $v_j$ regardless of $D$.

Comment: Thanks that's where I got stuck as well but your explanation makes sense. It's true that given hypothesis we can get the vjs but the hypothesis depends on D but I suppose that's different than the condition above.